# Нужна помощь в написании рекурсивного метода c#

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Есть довольно тривиальная задача, в которой я просто запутался.

Есть лист, в котором хранится блок информации (не обязательно такой, это просто пример):

```
asdf
[1,2]
fff
[4,5]
```

Нужно прогнать это через рекурсивный метод, чтоб в конце получить все возможные варианты строк по данному шаблону.

То есть, как результат должен выйти `List<string>`:

```
asdf1fff4
asdf1fff5
asdf2fff4
asdf2fff5
```

Рекурсивность нужна, чтоб количество блоков могло варьироваться, а не быть строго заданным. Количество букв между запятыми в скобках неизвестно. Все варианты для подстановки заданы через запятую и никак иначе.

Свои поделки выкладывать не буду, так как явно ничем не помогут -- однозначно хрень написал.

Comment: `new IEnumerable<string>[] {new[] {"asdf"}, new[] {"1", "2"}, new[] {"fff"}, new[] {"4", "5"}}.Aggregate((e, d)=>e.SelectMany(_=>d, string.Concat))`

Comment: @PetSerAl, напишите ответ, зачем писать это в комментариях?

Comment: @PetSerAl - Не представляю как даный здесь код можно переписать под следующие условия: * количество блоков может варьироваться, а не быть строго заданным. * Количество символов между запятыми в скобках неизвестно.  Но способ сам по себе хорош и для меня нов. Так что все равно спасибо)

Comment: @Andrew Так как парсинг рекурсии не требует, то я исходил из того, что с ним у Вас проблем нет. Мой код работает с любым `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, главное, чтобы внутренние перечисления могли быть перечислены несколько раз.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При помощи `SelectMany` можно получить декартово произведение двух множеств. `Aggregate` позволяет с лёгкостью применить данную операцию к произвольному числу множеств. `DefaultIfEmpty` помогает избежать исключения, когда множеств нет.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Parse(IEnumerable<string> rawData) {
    return
        rawData.Select(s =>
            Regex.Match(
                s,
                "^(\\[((?<Item>[^,]*),)*(?<Item>[^,]*)]|(?<Item>.*))$",
                RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture|RegexOptions.Singleline
            ).Groups["Item"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray()
        );
}
public static IEnumerable<string> All(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> parsedData) {
    return 
        parsedData.DefaultIfEmpty(new[] { "Отсутствуют исходные данные." }).
        Aggregate((e, d) => e.SelectMany(_ => d, string.Concat));
}
public static void Test() {
    IEnumerable<string> rawData = new[] { "asdf", "[1,2]", "fff", "[4,5]" };
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> parsedData = Parse(rawData);
    IEnumerable<string> all = All(parsedData);
    foreach(string s in all) {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да я, как-то, сначала не додумался парсить через rawData.Select(s => s.Trim('[').Trim(']').Split(',') ) что б вышел аррей аррейов (так будет немного быстрее чем предложеный вариант через регекс). Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо @PetSerAI -- с его помощью был написан следующий код:

```
private static string[] Generate(IEnumerable<string> rawData)
{
      IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> parsedData = rawData.Select(s =>
                        s.Trim('[').Trim(']').Split(',') );

      return parsedData.DefaultIfEmpty(new[] { "Отсутствуют исходные данные." })
              .Aggregate((e, d) => e.SelectMany(_ => d, string.Concat))
              .ToArray();
}
```